# How to create a mock inside the function under test

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I have a set of functions, which uses the pool of objects. This pool has been mocked. It works fine in most of the cases. But in some functions i call the methods of objects from the pool. So i need to mock this objects too.

Lets say:

```
// ObjectGeter is a interface that is mocked
type ObjectGeter interface {
    GetObject(id int) ObjectType, error
}

// this function is under test 
func SomeFunc(og ObjectGeter,id int, otherArgument SomeType) error {
    // some actions with otherArgument  
    // and may be return an error

    obj, err := og.GetObject(id)
    if err !=nil {
        return errors.New("GetObject error")
    }

    rezult, err := obj.SomeMethod()
    if err !=nil {
        return errors.New("One of internal errors")
    }

    return rezult, nil
}
```

Is there a way to test whole this function? I can create interface **SomeMethoder** which wraps the **SomeMethod()**, but i can't find the way how to assign it to **obj** inside **SomeFunc** without changing the signature of **GetObject** to **GetObject(id int) SomeMethoder,error**.

Currently i see the one approach - testing by a parts.

Comment: You have to change the signature if you want `GetObject` to return a mockable instance. You should however re-consider whether you really need a mock to test that functionality, maybe the ObjectGetter mock could return an instance of ObjectType that is easily testable without introducing another mock.

Comment: The main problem stems from mocking at all. Stop mocking the way other languages promote it. You have got an ObjectGeter interface and to test SomeFun you have to provide and ObjectGeter which works properly: It must provide Objects and these must have SomeMethod. Instead of a crippled attempt to inject mocked zombies just provide proper Objects with proper, known, consistent and thus testable state. Don't mock. Write fakes or stubs.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i'v found without of changing of paradigm is a wrapper. It is pretty trivial but may be some one will need it once.

Originally i have some type:

```
type PoolType struct {...}

func (p *PoolType)GetObject(id int) (ObjectType, error) {...}
```

and interface, that wraps **PoolType.GetObject** and that i'v mocked.

Now i have the interface:

```
type SomeMethoder interface {
    SomeMethod() (ResultType, error)
}
```

to wrap object returned by **PoolType.GetObject()**.

To produce it i have interface:

```
type ObjectGeter interface {
    GetObject(id int) (SomeMethoder, error)
}
```

and type

```
type MyObjectGeter struct {
    pool *PoolType
}

func New(pool *PoolType) *MyObjectGeter {
    return &MyObjectGeter{pool: pool}
}

func (p *MyObjectGeter)GetObject(id int) (SomeMethoder, error) {
    return p.pool.GetObject(id)
}
```

that implements it.

So:

```
// this function is under test 
func SomeFunc(og ObjectGeter,id int, otherArgument SomeType) error {
    // some actions with otherArgument  
    // and may be return an error

    iface, err := og.GetObject(id)
    if err !=nil {
        return errors.New("GetObject error")
    }

    rezult, err := iface.SomeMethod()
    if err !=nil {
        return errors.New("One of internal errors")
    }

    return rezult, nil
}
```

is called by

```
og := New(pool)
SomeFunc(og,id,otherArgument)
```

in real work.

After all to test whole **SomeFunc** i have to:

```
func TestSomeFuncSuccess (t *testing.T) {
    controller := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer controller.Finish()

    objectGeter := mocks.NewMockObjectGeter(controller)
    someMethoder := mocks.NewMockSomeMethoder(controller)

    gomock.InOrder(
        args.objectGeter.EXPECT().
            GetObject(correctIdCOnst).
            Return(someMethoder, nil),
        args.someMethoder.EXPECT().
            SomeMethod().
            Return(NewResultType(...),nil).
            Times(args.test.times[1]),
    )

    result, err := SomeFunc(objectGeter,correctIdCOnst,otherArgumentConst)
    // some checks
}
```

So, the only untested part is **MyObjectGeter.GetObject** that is enough for me.